# am trying a Spring boot example but it is showing following error.. what should i do?

Tags: spring-boot

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-03-26 11:37:05.248 ERROR 9332 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:175)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.disableRegistry()V
```

The method's class, org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_77/lib/ext/tomcat-coyote.jar!/org/apache/tomcat/util/modeler/Registry.class
jar:file:/C:/Users/hp/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.31/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/org/apache/tomcat/util/modeler/Registry.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_77/lib/ext/tomcat-coyote.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry

Answer (score 0):

please put some of your code snippet here, such as application.properties file, main and ... . or you can push your application to github and put your repository address here then i'll check it.